# NodeJS Axios: The "listener" argument must be of type Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have simple function that uses axios to make an API call. It is called multiple times and after few I get the same error on every of them:

```
Trace: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type Function. Received type object
    at checkListener (events.js:77:11)
    at TLSSocket.once (events.js:326:3)
    at Object.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1425:13)
    at Agent.createConnection (https.js:125:22)
    at Agent.createSocket (_http_agent.js:242:26)
    at Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js:201:10)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:276:16)
    at Object.request (https.js:309:10)
    at RedirectableRequest._performRequest (webpack:///./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js?:169:24)
    at new RedirectableRequest (webpack:///./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js?:66:8) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

I am using Vue in my app for frontend, but this function is called from NodeJS backend.

Axios instance:

```
this.axios = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    responseType: 'json'
});
```

Axios call:

```
await this.axios({
    url: this.url,
    method: 'POST',           
    headers: this.headers,
    responseType: 'json',
    withCredentials: true,
    params: {
        input: 'test',
        method: method
    },
    data: callData
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: How do you have axios configured?

Comment: Is it installed on your backend and required properly?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I've updated the question with it. Also - I've tried removing node_modules and running npm install, and the result is same.

Comment: Have you installed and required it with Node?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights yes, the whole project uses the same node_modules for both. In Node I used `import axios from 'axios';` to import it.

Comment: Can you do it that way? I've always used separate node_modules for my frontend/backend and installed axios in both

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I guess, new to Vue, so just followed the vue-cli getting started and got it that way.

Comment: Do you have two separate package.json files for vue and node?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights no. both share it

Comment: Could you post the full file with your axios request? I think you're calling it from Vue instead of Node

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Past the hour I've tried to recreate this with only node - no error. But my app depends on electron and this is called from electron, so when running this with electron (without Vue) I got same error. So it's caused by electron.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by electron. I had to use electron net library to do the requests instead of axios.

Thanks to @Daniel_Knights for suggestions.